# Socket.io connecting to localhost from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, firefox-addon

I'm having trouble connecting to a local websocket using Socket.io from within a firefox add-on context script.

I can run the same script hosted in a webpage so the server checks out.

Relevant manifest settings

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' *127.0.0.1*; object-src 'self'",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.website.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
        }
```

content_script.js

```
$.getScript('http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js',function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8081');
  
    socket.on('connect', function() {
         socket.emit('config',
             {
                 server: {
                     port: 3333,
                     host: '127.0.0.1'
                 },
                 client: {
                     port: 3334,
                     host: '127.0.0.1'
                 }
             }
         );
         socket.on('message', function(obj) {
             console.log(obj);
         });

         socket.emit('message', '/foo/bar 1 2 3');
     });

});
```

It fails without error message on initialisation.

Reading forums I can see there have been a lot of changes over the years to firefox websocket security, but many of the about:config changes or manifest rule suggests seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might stumble on this, as I suspected it was the content security policy that is real quiet about not allowing this sort of connection.

Undoubtedly there is a good solution to this using the manifest but since I'm only running this locally I installed a seperate firefox developer version, limited the sites it could access, and switched off csp in about:config